# Writing a test to Mock filename

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a method that is called from the windows form back code it accepts `string[]` filename. The issues I feel guilty when writing unit test for `ReadFile()`. Since I dont have a way to mock tthe file name. Kindly assist if there is a way to mock the filename

This is the method

```
 public Results ImportData(string[] fileNames)
        {
            List<ListViews> listViewDataItems = new List<ListViews>();

            try
            {
                foreach (var filename in fileNames)
                {

                    var readResults = ReadFile(filename);//unit test for this
                    var mapResults = MappingData(readResults);
                    var listViewDataItemsMiniBucket = ImportToDatabase(mapResults, filename);
                    listViewDataItems.Add(listViewDataItemsMiniBucket);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogger.Instance.SendErrorToFile(ex);
                return new Results
                {
                    DescripText = ex.ToString(),
                    Success = false
                };
            }
            return new Results { Success = true, Objects = listViewDataItems };
        }
```

FileName Function

```
 public DataSet ReadFile(string filePath)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var reader = GetExcelDataReaderExtension(stream, filePath);

                using (reader)
                {
                    return reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                    {
                        ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                        {
                            FilterRow = rowReader => rowReader.Depth > Constants.HeaderIndex
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Unit test below

```
  [Fact]
        public void ReadTest()
        {

            Import test = new Import();
            var filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Files\\";
            var fileName = "Refund Cases Cancelled in November 2016 - filenameCopy.xlsx";
            var file = filePath + fileName;

            var readResults = test.ReadFile(file);
            Assert.False(readResults.HasErrors);
        }
```

Unit test ImportData()

```
 [Fact]
        public void ImportData()
        {
            Import test = new Import();
            var filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Files\\";

            var files = new[]
            {
             filePath+"Refund Cases Cancelled in November 2016 - Copy - Copy.xlsx",
             filePath+"Refund Cases Cancelled in November 2016 - Copy - Copy.xlsx"
            };
            var results = test.ImportData(files).Success;

            Assert.True(results);
        }
```

Comment: What is your method under test?

Comment: @AdamG is ReadFile(file) & ImportData(files) the issues mocking those files

Comment: What I mean is that if you're testing ReadFile(file), you would put some known good (or bad) file, ask your method to read it, then assert about the result it provided. If you're testing importfile, you may want to mock the response from readfile. Your question isn't clear on which you are doing.

Comment: Separate those implementation concerns into their own concerns. The current code is tightly coupled to implementation concerns which make testing in isolation difficult. `ReadFile` is self contained enough to become its own service